# HTML file explorer from REST api

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I am creating my own RESTApi that works like a personal google drive. I have created a very backbones backend for testing. I set up a GET request that displays the folders/files for each subdirectory in json.

For example calling `GET http://serverIP:3000/storage/root/` displays this json data

```
{
    "path": "/home/cameron/TestRestApi/api/stoage/root",
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "path": "/home/cameron/TestRestApi/api/stoage/root/Images",
            "name": "Images",
            "children": [

                    "path": "/home/cameron/TestRestApi/api/stoage/root/Images/Image1.jpg",
                    "name": "Image1.jpg",
                    "size": 68994,
                    "extension": ".jpg",
                    "type": "file"
                },
                {
                    "path": "/home/cameron/TestRestApi/api/stoage/root/Images/image2.jpg",
                    "name": "image2.jpg",
                    "size": 68994,
                    "extension": ".jpg",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ],
            "size": 1172898,
            "type": "directory"
        },
        {
            "path": "/home/cameron/TestRestApi/api/stoage/root/documents",
            "name": "documents",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "/home/cameron/TestRestApi/api/stoage/root/documents/document1.text",
                    "name": "document1.text",
                    "size": 0,
                    "extension": ".text",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ],
            "size": 0,
            "type": "directory"
        }
    ],
    "size": 1172898,
    "type": "directory"
}
```

So my question is how do I make a front end for this? 
Like I want it to create buttons for each of the folders and then when you press the button it makes another git request with that buttons name which would be the file path name and displays the folders/files in that folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/) plugin, it is written in javascript and can help you create a file tree.

Comment: Thank you! thats what i was looking for. Now i just need to figure out how to reorder the JSON to fit with what jsTree needs